# Typescript compiled file cannot find module

Tags: typescript

I have an exported module in one file(parser.js) in Typescript project and I did not generate any error during the compilation phase ,but the Compiled file can't work, This makes me feel confused

```js
// parser.d.ts
declare module 'parser' {
    interface Parser {
        parser(url: string):string
    }

    export class UrlParser implements Parser {
        parser(url: string): string  {
            return  url.includes('https') ? url.replace('https', 'http') : '';
        }
    }
}
```

```
// parser.js
export default class UrlParser {
    parser(url)  {
        return  url.includes('https') ? url.replace('https', 'http') : '';
    }
}
```

```js
/// <reference path="../lib/parser.d.ts" />
import * as Parser  from 'parser';

let urlParser = new Parser.UrlParser()
console.log(urlParser.parser('https://www.baidu.com'))
```

```
// compiled file I got
"use strict";
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) result[k] = mod[k];
    result["default"] = mod;
    return result;
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
/// <reference path="../lib/parser.d.ts" />
var Parser = __importStar(require("parser"));
var urlParser = new Parser.UrlParser();
console.log(urlParser.parser('https://www.baidu.com'));
```

I got an error when I executed the node ./dest/main/js command.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'parser'
```

Comment: Can you share how you generated the parser.js? Or maybe package.json regarding ts files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a relative path (e.g. `'./dest/lib/parser'`) in that import statement since by default `require` is going to look in `node_modules` if a path is not passed (where as TypeScript can be told where `'parser'` is).

You could also add a `package.json` file to the same folder as `parser.js` with the contents `{ name: 'parser' }` which would allow it to be found via `require('parser')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I want to import javascript file in the typescript project with type system. What should I do?

Comment: I referenced [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html),Did I understand wrong?

Comment: It's impossible for me to say whether or not you understood wrong, I'd have to see how your entire project is structured and what your tsconfig looks like. You shouldn't import declaration files, you should import real modules. Change `import * as Parser from 'parser'` to `import Parser from './path/to/parser';` and the import won't fail.